# Ag-Grid header checkbox and individual checkbox selection limit to 5 rows

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Am working on an **AG-Gird** angular project. Have a requirement to limit the row selection up to 5 rows. Programmatically I did the functionality, but have some issues with it.
This is the code I have

```
onRowSelectionChanged(): void {

    if (this.limitRowSelection()) {
      return;
    }
    
    //call Api
    // call Api                                   

  }
  
 limitRowSelection(): Boolean {
    const selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();
    this.selectedRowsCount = selectedRows.length;
    let status = false;
    if (this.selectedRowsCount >= 5) {
      while (this.selectedRowsCount > 5) {
        this.gridApi.deselectIndex(this.selectedRowsCount - 1, true);
        //this.gridApi.deselectNode(selectedRows[this.selectedRowsCount - 1]);
        this.selectedRowsCount--;
      }
      status = true;
    }

    return status;
  }
```

The issue I found is that whenever the **limitRowSelection** return true. it will not call the below APIs because I set **return;**
Onther issue is, while calling **gridApi.deselectIndex()**, it will trigger **onRowSelectionChanged** method again and again.How can i solve this issue.
Do we have any other option for setting the row selection limit?

I have read the AG-agird documentation from the below link

https://www.ag-grid.com/

Thanks in advance.

Looking for a better solution

Comment: dont make the api call on row selection, instead do it on rmc item click

Comment: @NarenMurali what is rmc item click

Comment: read about [contextmenu](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/context-menu/)

Comment: actually i need to limit row selection up to 5.

Comment: that you do, but api call do it on the context menu only

Comment: onRowSelectionChanged call multiple times.how to solve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247521/discussion-between-arj-and-naren-murali).